# Is it possible to make a call out to a remote server from within a SharePoint 2013 app?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am very new to SharePoint development as well as SharePoint overall, so I apologize if this question seems like a no-brainer.  I'm currently working on a SharePoint 2013 app and I'm wondering if it's possible to make a call out to some URL from within the SharePoint environment.  Basically, I want to do this within an event receiver after some action is done to a list, and from there I want to make a call to some web service on my server to update my system.  Using the REST API to poll the SharePoint server isn't a good option for this scenario since it won't scale very well.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with SharePoint 2013 apps you can access any resource using standardized APIs. In addition to REST SharePoint is offering the JS Client Object Model (CSOM).

In order to access data from another web than the current one, your app needs the permission to interact with the entire tenant.

If you're trying to query data from another host, you have to use JSONP because of the same origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

if you are building an app using the "new App Model" for wiring up Remote Event Receivers it is possible to do anything, in which your app hosting framework/environment allows you to.  If you are building a Classic App (Farm Solutions) you'll have access to perform operations which are allowable from the SharePoint servers directly...typically this is a lot as GAC deployed assemblies are granted full trust.

depending on what you are trying to do and what kind of resources you app will consume.  I'd consider moving the dependancies away from SharePoint and building using the new App Model versus the older farm solutions.  As you sound like you are starting in SharePoint, this gives you an opportunity to learn the new ways of doing development for SharePoint.

Lastly, you might consider building a workflow.  Not sure what kind of app you are building but the new workflow capabilities include actions which can make RESTful calls.  Potentially making your application a "no code" solution.  Again it all really depends.